# TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "vector") to tuple

Tags: python, vector, concatenation, tuples, pygame

I am new to python and pygame and I am trying to learn the basics of vectors and classes and in the process i managed to screw up horribly and I am struggling in understanding and fixing the error message in the title.

here is the code for my Vector class:

```
import math

class Vector(object):

    #defaults are set at 0.0 for x and y
    def __init__(self, x=0.0, y=0.0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    #allows us to return a string for print
    def __str__(self):
        return "(%s, %s)"%(self.x, self.y)

    # from_points generates a vector between 2 pairs of (x,y) coordinates
    @classmethod
    def from_points(cls, P1, P2):
        return cls(P2[0] - P1[0], P2[1] - P1[1])

    #calculate magnitude(distance of the line from points a to points b
    def get_magnitude(self):
        return math.sqrt(self.x**2+self.y**2)

    #normalizes the vector (divides it by a magnitude and finds the direction)
    def normalize(self):
        magnitude = self.get_magnitude()
        self.x/= magnitude
        self.y/= magnitude

    #adds two vectors and returns the results(a new line from start of line ab to end of line bc)
    def __add__(self, rhs):
        return Vector(self.x +rhs.x, self.y+rhs.y)

    #subtracts two vectors
    def __sub__(self, rhs):
        return Vector(self.x - rhs.x, self.y-rhs.y)

    #negates or returns a vector back in the opposite direction
    def __neg__(self):
        return vector(-self.x, -self.y)

    #multiply the vector (scales its size) multiplying by negative reverses the direction
    def __mul__(self, scalar):
        return Vector(self.x*scalar, self.y*scalar)

    #divides the vector (scales its size down)
    def __div__(self, scalar):
        return Vector(self.x/scalar, self.y/scalar)
```

and here is the code for my program:

```
#The simple mouse move game by Ramon Cabral


#imports
import pygame, sys, Vector
from pygame.locals import *

#game init
pygame.init()

#screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600),0,32)

#images
mouse_file = 'mouse.png'
MOUSE = pygame.image.load(mouse_file).convert_alpha()


#variables
bgcolor = (255,255,255)
position = (100.0,100.0)
heading = Vector.vector()

#clock and speed
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
speed = 250.0


#main game function
while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            destination = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            heading = Vector.vector.from_points(position, destination)
            heading.normalize()

    screen.fill(bgcolor)
    screen.blit(MOUSE, position)

    time_passed = clock.tick(30.)
    time_passed_seconds = time_passed/1000.0

    distance_moved = time_passed_seconds*speed
    position += heading * distance_moved

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: can you provide the traceback

Answer (score 1):

Give your class a `tuple` method:

```
class Vector(object):
    ...

    def tuple(self):
        return (self.x, self.y)
```

Change:

```
position = (100.0,100.0)
```

To:

```
position = Vector.vector(100.0,100.0)
```

And:

```
screen.blit(MOUSE, position)
```

To:

```
screen.blit(MOUSE, position.tuple())
```

You're adding incompatible types.

Comment: Thanks for the help. What you are saying makes a lot of sense but for some reason now I get a different message.                      position = Vector(100.0,100.0)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: @rrcm: Change my `Vector` to `Vector.vector`

Comment: I think i just made a horrible class. Here is the error I get now.   position = Vector.vector(100.0,100.0)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'vector'

Comment: @rrcm: How did you run this code before? `Vector.vector()` should be defined. Or is it `Vector.Vector` (capitalized)?

Comment: position = (100.0,100.0) is how i ran it before. and heading = Vector.vector() worked but i guess it doesnt work for position for some reason

Comment: I personally prefer to use arrays in python. They have a lot of the functionality of vectors but are also significantly easier to use

Comment: @Roboinventor: Do you mean lists? I can't really see how you could  cross product two lists.